# How do I find out the current scaling factor?

Tags: graph, gnuplot, scale

I am using gnuplot 4.0 and want to move up and down in a graph. I have already found out how to bind my arrow key to a redefinition of the vertical range, but I don't know the current scaling (with mouse-right-click, move, mouse-right-click and another mouse click).

1. Is there a system variable I can read out ?
2. How is the current scaling kept track of ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes `GPVAL_X_MIN` and `GPVAL_X_MAX` (and so on for y, x2, y2, z, ...) gives you the current bounds of these variables. You can view list of all variables including internal and user-defined with `show variables all` or use `show variables GPVAL` to view only those that start with GPVAL

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
It is essential to mention that these variables get auto-created upon the first plot, but NOT BEFORE gnuplot 4.6. :-)

Comment: I just want to tell that I have given up using gnuplot soon after this exchange here on stackoverflow, because there is no documentation that is fairly good enough what works in which version etc. Sad, but true.